# Python: Only allow attributes to be set that have a @property decorator

Tags: python, getter-setter

```
class MyClass():
   def __init__(self):
      self.attribute_1 = "foo"
      self.attribute_2 = "bar"
 
   @property
   def attribute_1(self):
     return self._attribute_1

   @attribute_1.setter
   def attribute_1(self,s):
     self._attribute_1 = s

   @property
   def attribute_2(self):
     return self._attribute_2

   @attribute_2.setter
   def attribute_2(self,s):
     self._attribute_2 = s

>>> ob = MyClass()
>>> ob.attribute_1 = 'fizz' #Ok
>>> ob.atribute_1 = 'buzz' #want to throw an exception because this has no setter or @property def
```

I would like my class to complain if we try and set an attribute that has not been decorated with property and a setter. I have tried using [slots](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) but can't get it working with the property decorator. `'attribute' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable`

Any thoughts?

Comment: the `__slots__` would be `["_attribute_1", "_attribute_2"]` since those are the 2 variables you use as actual instance variables, (you don't include methods or properties in slots) does that not work for you?

Comment: @tadhg Thats it!

Comment: This is kinda antithetical to Python. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I'm a mad man.

Comment: As an aside, these properties are absolutely pointless, and you should just use regular attributes

Comment: yea, it's called example code to get share a concept. It's not supposed to land the space shuttle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__slots__` should contain all instance variables, in your case it is `_attribute_1` and `_attribute_2` (the ones with underscores used internally) so just do that:

```
class MyClass():
   __slots__ = ["_attribute_1", "_attribute_2"]
   pass # rest of implementation
```

note that if your property is just directly forwarding you might as well just put the public variables in the slots and only have properties for fields that need more validation or other logic.  having slots is effectively a property really:

```
>>> MyClass._attribute_1
<member '_attribute_1' of 'MyClass' objects>
```